# How can I use jinja2 to join with quotes in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible list value:

```
hosts = ["site1", "site2", "site3"]
```

if I try this:

```
hosts | join(", ")
```

I get:

```
site1, site2, site3
```

But I want to get:

```
"site1", "site2", "site3"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best solution seems to be

```
hosts | map('quote') | join(', ')
```

You can also use the `join` including the quotes, and ensure the whole expression is surrounded with quotes, to get the left and right outer quote. But this will leave empty quotes, in case the list is empty. Depending on your scenario:

```
"{{ hosts | join('", "') }}"
```

or

```
'"' + hosts | join('", "') + '"'
```

or

```
"'\"' + hosts | join('\", \"') + '\"'"
```

Comment: I know this is 4 years old, but ... This fails on the ther first and last entry of the list:  You end up with      site1", "site2", "site3

Comment: That's why you have quotes around the whole thing.

Comment: wondering if this solution still works in the latest ansible. i did the test and getting error related to quotes. --We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value--

Comment: still works you just need to escape the quotes `joined_string: "{{ hosts | join('\", \"') }}"` missing first and last quotes need to be added when you use the string `new_string: " '"' + {{ joined_string }} + '"' "`

Answer (score 4):

The previous answer leaves `""` if the list is empty. There is another approach that may be more robust, e.g. for assigning the joined list as a string to a different variable (example with single quotes):

```
{{ hosts | map("regex_replace","(.+)","\'\\1\'") | join(',')}}
```

Comment: Maybe my context is different, but this only worked for me after removing the excessive quoting/escaping: `{{ hosts | map("regex_replace","(.+)","\1") | join(',')}}` - but this was definitely useful.

Answer (score 4):

Ansible has a `to_json`, `to_nice_json`, or a `to_yaml` in it's filters:

```
{{ some_variable | to_json }}
{{ some_variable | to_yaml }}
```

Useful if you are outputting a JSON/YAML or even (it's a bit cheeky, but JSON mostly works) a python config file (ie Django settings).

For reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data

Answer (score 0):

From a json file file_name.json array like this

```
"hosts": [
    "site1",
    "site2",
    "site3"
]
```

Set_fact from a json file

```
- name: Set variables from parameters file
  set_fact:
    vars_from_json: "{{ lookup('file', 'file_name.json') | from_json }}"
```

Use join with double quote and comma, and wrap all around in double quote

```
- name: Create host list
  set_fact:    
    host_list: "{{ '\"' + vars_from_json.hosts | join('\"'', ''\"') + '\"' }}"
```